# Firefox: Using multiple instances with different profiles?

Tags: firefox, user-profiles, multiple-instances

Let's say, Firefox's instance is running with profile 1.
Is it now possible, to start a new Firefox instance with profile 2?

Normally, when Firefox is already running, no new instance is created.
Instead, just a new browser window is opened.

*Note: By saying "profile", I'm referring to Firefox user profiles.*

Comment: try searching. it is the number one question regarding firefox in superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [an article](http://lifehacker.com/231646/geek-to-live--manage-multiple-firefox-profiles) from Lifehacker dealing with this. It's not extremely complicated, I've used this a couple of times.

Comment: Wow! Couldn't imagine that it's so simple and supported out-of-the-box ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can do it from the command line:

```
firefox -no-remote -P profile_name
```

Comment: First run 'firefox --profilemanager' to set up separate profiles.

Comment: `-P` is a shorthand for that

Comment: It isn't really: -P says 'load the named profile' it will only open ProfileManager it the profile you've named doesn't exist.

Comment: `firefox -no-remote -P` brings up the profile manager for me. Anyway, you can avoid dealing with the Profile Manager at all using the `-profile` switch as described in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try [MultiFirefox](http://davemartorana.com/multifirefox/):

> MultiFirefox is a small launcher
>   utility that allows you to run
>   multiple versions of Firefox
>   side-by-side.  It helps you set up
>   multiple profiles (one or more for
>   each version of Firefox), remembers
>   your last launch preferences for easy
>   launching, has auto-updating built in
>   for when we make improvements, and is
>   100% open source, MIT licensed.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please provide more information then just a link. SU is a repository of answers and desciptive answers are encouraged.

Comment: It is an external tool, which allows multiple instances of firefox to be started, also with different profiles and different sets of addons.

Comment: Also, it is way more comfortable than using the built-in profile manager. Give it a try, a frined uses it all the time: He launches one instance for web developing with loads of add-ons, and one sleek with minimal add-ons for the usual web surfing, without the add-on bloat.

Comment: @brandstaetter: I edited your answer a bit to add more info about the app from the authors site. Hope you don't mind! Also, cool little app :)

Comment: awesome, thanks @alex. I'm still getting used to this here, Hope to improve my skills soon :)

Comment: It's not very hard; you'll learn as you go along. When composing your answers, use the buttons to add hyperlinks and edit your text as you see fit.

Answer (score 3):

Using an unx environement, you can use a command like :

```
env MOZ_NO_REMOTE=1 firefox -P Profile2
```

Using a windows or Mac OS X env, I don't know how you can do it

Comment: OSX is pretty much an unx environment, so it works there as well.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using the Profile manager (the `-P` switch described in @hasen's answer) is to specify the path to profile directly in the command line.

`firefox -no-remote -profile absolute-path-to-the-profile-dir` will create the directory specified (if it doesn't exist) and use it as the profile.

Example on Windows:

```
C:\Progra~1\Firefox\firefox.exe -no-remote -profile C:\FxProfiles\myprofile
```

On OS X it is slightly more complicated:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -foreground \
   -no-remote -profile /Users/me/fx-profiles/myprofile
```

`-foreground` switches from the terminal window to Firefox. Note that on 10.5 you have to use [an even more complicated comand](http://asqueella.blogspot.ru/2010/12/dyld-unknown-required-load-command.html) to work around the `dyld` error.

See also [Starting Firefox with a specified profile from the dock (Mac OS X)](https://superuser.com/questions/75271/starting-firefox-with-a-specified-profile-from-the-dock-mac-os-x).