# How to open multiple firefox windows with distinct sessions?

Tags: firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Firefox: Using multiple instances with different profiles?](https://superuser.com/questions/41496/firefox-using-multiple-instances-with-different-profiles)

I'd like to open two or more firefox windows and have distinct sessions in each.

For instance:

I open window 1, and go to gmail.com and sign in.

I open window 2, and go to gmail.com - I'm not currently signed in with this window. So I can sign into a different account.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/41496/firefox-using-multiple-instances-with-different-profiles

Comment: Take a look at the solution offered in the duplicated question, it will fix your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the thread mentioned by hyperslug, but to condense it (and add something):

You need to use multiple [profiles](http://lifehacker.com/231646/geek-to-live--manage-multiple-firefox-profiles), together with either:

[CookieSwap](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3255)

> CookieSwap enables you to easily swap
>   all your cookies so that you can be
>   logged in to multiple web e-mail
>   accounts (like Gmail and Yahoo! mail)
>   as different users at the same time
>   and quickly switch between them.

[MultiFirefox](http://davemartorana.com/multifirefox/)

> MultiFirefox is a small launcher
>   utility that allows you to run
>   multiple versions of Firefox
>   side-by-side.  It helps you set up
>   multiple profiles (one or more for
>   each version of Firefox), remembers
>   your last launch preferences for easy
>   launching, has auto-updating built in
>   for when we make improvements, and is
>   100% open source, MIT licensed.