# Log in with two accounts (e.g., in Gmail) in a single Firefox window

Tags: firefox, gmail, user-accounts

I have two Gmail accounts.

I'd like to log in to both of them at the same time *in a single Firefox window.*

How would I go about it?

I know one suggestion is IETab, but that fix has too much of a duct tape feel to it.

There are some other questions covering this, but not necessarily within the same Firefox window:

- [How to Log Into a Web App Simultaneously with Different Account?](https://superuser.com/questions/44903/how-to-log-into-a-web-app-simultaneously-with-different-account)
- [Firefox: Using multiple instances with different profiles?](https://superuser.com/questions/41496/firefox-using-multiple-instances-with-different-profiles)
- [How to open multiple firefox windows with distinct sessions?](https://superuser.com/questions/48854/how-to-open-multiple-firefox-windows-with-distinct-sessions-closed) [closed]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gmail now supports [using multiple accounts simultaneously](http://gmailblog.blogspot.in/2010/08/access-two-gmail-accounts-at-once-in.html) on the same browser.

Answer (score 9):

Also, if you are just checking mail. You can use one gmail account to check the mail of another http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=21288

Comment: Very good point!

Answer (score 6):

[Mashable](http://mashable.com/2008/06/07/log-into-several-gmail-accounts-same-time/) has "5 Ways To Log Into Several Gmail Accounts At The Same Time":

> 1. Multiple browsers
> 2. Master account to which you forward all other accounts
> 3. [IE Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/1419) (Windows only; basically an additional browser within one window)
> 4. [Gmail Manager](http://www.longfocus.com/firefox/gmanager/)
> 5. [Google Account Multi-Login](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/16341) ([Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/748) script)

**For Internet Explorer 8 users :**

start Internet Explorer with **-NOMERGE** argument

> iexplore.exe -nomerge

then each instance started will run in a isolated session environment so you can open another Gmail account or any other web service.

Comment: +1 for #5.  Also, perhaps you might add multiple user profiles to that list.

Comment: +1 for multiple profiles, however he just does not want it.
whenever i have the same need, though, i run arora browser. any lightweight browser would do. thunderbird would do.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, this can't be done well and only works in IETab because the IE engine is embedded into a firefox tab.

One option is to install [Prism](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6665), an official firefox extension and run one or both instances of GMail as an 'application'. This doesn't work in a single window but is a nice solution, and gives you a faster (no addons) window for your GMail to run in.

Answer (score 1):

As Revolter mentioned [Google Account Multi-Login](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/16341) greasemonkey script can allow you to login into multiple accounts.

Comment: +1 for the link that was missing from Revolter's answer and even the article (s)he referred to.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CookieSwap](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3255).

See a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/44903/how-to-log-into-a-web-app-simultaneously-with-different-account).

Answer (score 0):

http://webmailnotifier.mozdev.org/ - it will check any number of different types of email accounts. You can open the relevant webmail page from a link in the plugin's menu, sidebar, icon.