# Two Google accounts in firefox for email/reader/openid

Tags: firefox, login, gmail, openid

I usually checking my personal gmail account account at work, and I have another gmail account for work/professional purpose.

Now I am starting to see more sites using OpenID. The problem I am facing is that I want to check my gmail from firefox, but I want to use my work google account to login with OpenID website.

Is there an easy to do so? Of course one way is to logout my personal account, login my work account, OpenID login to those sites. Second way is to use another browser for my personal gmail and firefox for work, but are there a better way because I hate using two browsers at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you use Google Chrome (or other Chromium-based browser), you can just have a "portable" version of it installed for this.

I know this is sub-optimal but so far that's been the best solution I could find while **almost** avoiding using different programs.

I use Google Chrome and keep a copy of [Iron Portable](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron_download.php) in a folder and I use it whenever I need to login multiple times to the same place.

If you're into Firefox, you can use [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) the same way.

The "portable" solution is cool because you can have as many "instances" of the portable browser as you want: just unzip it to different folders and each copy will run independently.

The fact they are independent is also the sub-optimal part :P
It won't share your history, bookmarks, etc.

Another option (quick-n-dirty) is to just use the Incognito Mode.
It will run into a separate session space, but is a bit of an inconvenience if you care about history, ability to reopen closed tabs and other things like that.
It will also only work if you need only two separate sessions.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 for incognito mode, this works exactly as expected.  cnt+shift+n opens a new window in incognito mode and you can sign into a different google account without losing your main account authentication status.

Answer (score 0):

You might find some answers here: [superuser: log-in-with-two-accounts-in-a-single-firefox-window](https://superuser.com/questions/58110/log-in-with-two-accounts-e-g-in-gmail-in-a-single-firefox-window)

Comment: yes I am aware of this SU question. But I think my problem is more complicate since OpenID is involved.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Sorry I can't help more!

Answer (score 0):

You could log into your work Googleaccount and use the [Webmail Notifier plugin](http://webmailnotifier.mozdev.org/) to keep an eye on gmail (and any number of mail accounts). You can open any of mail accounts from that plugin.

With [Google's new multiple account sign-in](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182343) considers the first account you signed in with to be the default, which would be the one that works for OpenID. Be warned it is very new and it is a big pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use [Multifox](http://br.mozdev.org/multifox/), but apparently the extension is not actively developed anymore. There is a beta which is supposed to work with Firefox 4, but I didn't test it myself.