# Multiple installations of Firefox

Tags: firefox, installation, browser

This might sound a little insane, but I'd like to have separate browsers for my everyday/research and social-network browsing. I could install another Browser like Chrome, Opera etc. but I am not very fond of the ones I found for privacy and feature reasons.

I think it is possible to install different versions, but I'd like an up-to-date version in both cases.

So is it possible? Maybe have a standalone version (I didn't find an official source)?

Comment: If its MS Windows platform you can always use [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) to run as many instances of a program (multiple sandboxie profiles)and they will seem to be running with a new profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be two ways to accomplish this:

**PortableApps**

To handle this I prefer to use the "Portable" version. You can set it up in different dirs for as many instances you want. Download [here](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable).

**Profile Manager** (I don't know how stable this is)

1. Close all running instances of Firefox
2. In the Run dialog box, type in:  `firefox.exe -p`
3. Follow the prompts on the screen to set up a profile

   *Repeat as many times as needed for multiple profiles*

Comment: I have not found an official source for a portable version of Firefox unfortunately.

Comment: I do not believe that Mozilla has released a portable version, However this one is one I use [PortableApps](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fportableapps.com%2Fapps%2Finternet%2Ffirefox_portable&ei=cxMoVZ-xCo72oATl0ICgDA&usg=AFQjCNGgyJiXIm2aZ2KxXMSOx3B2kST0kQ&bvm=bv.90491159,d.cGU)

Comment: I think I'll be fine with switching profiles!

Comment: The [LiberKey](http://www.liberkey.com/en.html) version also works well ;)

Comment: @TomTom  Alternatively, you can use [Profile Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/profileswitcher/) addon which allows to switch or run multiple profiles at the same time without closing running instances of Firefox. I myself use three profiles at a time.

Answer (score -1):

Create a Virtual Machine, install Linux on VM, Install FF -- poof, separated computer with separated FF browser, for free.

Also maybe check out this other SU question and answers: [Firefox: Using multiple instances with different profiles?](https://superuser.com/questions/41496/firefox-using-multiple-instances-with-different-profiles?rq=1)